# Jekyll LF/CRLF issue with git

Tags: git, newline, jekyll, lf

I have a Jekyll folder in which only the production part (`_site`) is tracked with git. When I run the command to serve the local site with `jekyll serve -w`, the files will be changed to LF or CRLF depending on the machine I'm working on: CRLF for Windows, LF for Mac. This is really annoying because all my files inside `_site` will be commited everytime I switch my OS.

I've tried to fix this in the git config file with `autocrlf = false`, but since the files are generated at a higher level by Jekyll it seems to have no impact at all.

Is there a way to tell Jekyll to generate all the files in a specific format, either LF or CRLF ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Three obvious solutions :

#### First solution : Jekyll plugin

To globally replace CR or CRLF by LF, the easiest way is to do it when files are written to destination.

This plugin overload the Jekyll:Convertible.write method :

```
module Jekyll
  module Convertible
    def write(dest)
      ### begin overloading
      # Replaces CR and CRLF by LF
      self.output = self.output.gsub(/\r\n?/, "\n")
      ### end overloading

      path = destination(dest)
      FileUtils.mkdir_p(File.dirname(path))
      File.open(path, 'wb') do |f|
        f.write(output)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Save this in _plugins/crlf.rb and it will automatically run at **jekyll build** time.

#### Second solution : Configure your code editor

Configure your code editor to use LF. If you can't, change editor.

Comment: The first solution didn't work for me unfortunately. Running a `jekyll build` will switch file format to CRLF on Windows anyways. I guess I'll give Vagrant a try.

Comment: I've edited my answer : added configure your code editor to use LF and not CRLF

Comment: I ended up using the second solution and set my editor settings to use Unix, which solved the issue. Thanks!