# GitHub Pages code highlighter adds extra space

Tags: github, jekyll, github-pages

I use GitHub pages to host a website. Everything works fine except syntax highlighter. It adds extra empty line if Java code line starts with `//` and does not update line numbers. When I run the same site locally everything is works fine. Here is an example.

[image: Wrong]

As you can see it added an empty line after `//` comment.

[image: Godd]

And if run locally everything is ok.

My _config.yml

```
gems:
  - jekyll-paginate
  - jekyll-sitemap # add /sitemap.xml file

paginate_path: /_pages/page:num

highlighter: rouge
markdown: kramdown
kramdown:
  input: GFM
```

[Hosted website](http://www.dennis-grinch.co.uk/aliquam/example/aliquam-post-example)

[Github pages](https://github.com/grrinchas/aliquam/tree/gh-pages)

How can I sort this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a line ending problem. You have to change CRLF to LF.

> [Configure your code editor to use LF. If you can't, change editor.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25685518/1548376)